# Determining how Dynamics CRM-2011 custom entity is stored in SQL Server CCRM database

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

A custom entity for storing email templates is created in my Dynamics CRM - 2011 on-premise instance. I can see the entity in CRM instance but not able to find it in SQL Server CCRM database. Any help on how to query the entity schema in DB?

I have to move all the templates stored to a new on-premise CRM instance. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find two tables:

> [*YourOrganization*_MSCRM].[dbo].[*EntitySchemaName*Base]
>
> [*YourOrganization*_MSCRM].[dbo].[*EntitySchemaName*ExtensionBase]

Answer (score 1):

Copying data directly into the CRM SQL database is unsupported. In general, the only supported direct use of CRM's SQL database is to read from the Filtered Views and create custom indexes.

It would be best to copy the templates to the new instance in a supported way.  Supported ways to import data into CRM include writing custom code against the SOAP or REST Organization Services, using an ETL tool that provides a Dynamics CRM Connector (such as Scribe or KingswaySoft on SSIS), and the Bulk Import Wizard.

Depending on how much data you're moving, the easiest way to go is probably to export to Excel and import into the new system via the Bulk Import Wizard.

Otherwise, the [CRM 2011 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004) provides the DLL's and examples for writing C# to hit the SOAP service, as well as an example JavaScript library for using the REST endpoint (sdk.rest.js).